# Timer Ticks 2 times in 1 interval time windows.forms.timer

Tags: c#, .net, timer, call, repeat

This is my project design, I have mainpage and sub-pages. When i click buttons on left button menu it calls sub-forms in this mainpages panel. Since I couldn't find my problem anywhere, I wanted to summarize them for you so that we could find out what could be causing the problem.

[image]

this is how i call my sideforms

```
            panel_content.Controls.Clear();
            home.TopLevel = false;
            panel_content.Controls.Add(home);
            home.Show();
```

When sub-forms timer ticks its repeats 2 times in 1 interval time. How can i solve this problem. I am using .net framework timer.

My timer function:

```
        private void timer_PlcConnect_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer_PlcConnect.Interval = 5000;
            MessageBox.Show("is it repeat");
        }
```

But when i change program.cs startup form to sub form. I mean not mainpage. It works normal. Its not repeating.

How can we solve it.

My sub forms describing:

```
        readonly Home home = new Home();
        readonly VeriOranlari veriOranlari = new VeriOranlari();
        readonly Simulasyon simulasyon = new Simulasyon();
        readonly Kalibrasyon kalibrasyon = new Kalibrasyon();
        readonly MailAyarlari mailAyarlari = new MailAyarlari();
        readonly Raporlama raporlama = new Raporlama();
        readonly Ayarlar ayarlar = new Ayarlar();
```

Comment: do not post images of code.

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess that you've subscribed the event twice. Please post your code as a text.

Comment: Unless your system is corrupt, which we can't help with, then the event is raised once per `Interval`. That's it, that's all. If your event handler is executed twice per event then you must have registered that event handler twice. Another possibility is that it's actually in two different forms that two different `Timers` are raising events. Are you stopping the `Timer` when you close the form? If not then it will continue to raise events.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean with "repeats 2 times in 1 interval time". Timers are supposed to call the tick method repeatedly, and the exact interval may fluctuate somewhat. So I would suggest posting your *actual problem*.

Comment: What is the `Interval` and how long is that message box open? `MessageBox.Show` will block the UI thread so, if the message box is open for longer than the `Interval`, the events will start to queue up. Instead of making us guess, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: My problem is when i don't use sub forms i mean don't show or don't use mainly. They ticks 2 times. If i use it mainly it ticks 1 time.

Comment: Definitely timer calling 1 time. When i create a new timer and add something it calls 2 times again.

Comment: @John It's not what you think. It opens MessageBox 2 times at the same time. After interval time it opens 2 MessageBox again.

Comment: Given that `MessageBox.Show` blocks until the message box is cleared, that should be impossible to do on a single thread. I can only conclude that either your project or system is broken or you're displaying at least one form on a thread other than the UI thread. If you set a breakpoint on that line, does it get hit twice - once for each message box - or does it just get hit once for the two message boxes?

Comment: Ugh! I just realised that you are using forms as controls. WHY?!?!?! User controls exist for a reason. Use them. I doubt that this is related to the issue but when you do things you shouldn't, bad stuff can happen.

Comment: @John I think the problem is because of it, but is there a different way?

Comment: I don't know what that means. If you're asking me whether your issue is because you're using forms as controls then I doubt it, but I can't rule it out. You still shouldn't be using forms as controls though. You should be using user controls. They are designed like forms but they are used like controls.

Comment: Yes, when i remove form describings on mainpage it ticks 1 time. But how can i change this system. Is there a example? @John

Comment: Do more than one of those forms contain a `Timer`? Is that the only place you're creating any of those forms? Is the `Enabled` property of the `Timer` set to `true` in the designer?

Comment: @John All of your questions answer is "yes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling side forms from mainpage and a sideform page. So which form my dublicater timer has is defined from homepage and sidepage. So I deleted sideform defines from sideform. Its solved.

If you implement a form in your mainform, don't implement it to other side forms. For dublicating.

```
readonly Anasayfa anasayfa = new Anasayfa();
```

I hope it is of use to someone.